# pagination links not working properly in codeigniter,

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to implement pagination using codeigniter. 
Situation is following:
I have only `3` article in my db, so I set per page limit to be `2` to test pagination.
Content is property break, inside first page I have first two articles and on second third article. Pagination link numbers are generated correctly.

When I'm on the first page I click on pagination `link (2)` which loads second page with it's content, but while I'm on this second page pagination link not working on `page 1, (1)` is not link at all, `(2)` is linked again?

What can be a problem?

This is my controller method

```
function pagination()
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->model('article_m');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite.com/en/news/pagination';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('articles')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 2;
        $config['num_links'] = 20;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);        
        $pag = $this->db->get('articles', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));        
        $data['records'] = $pag->result();

        $this->template->view('news/pagination', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add this also for your config

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

Comment: Yoooo... Thanks  Working Now... :)